# Cut element - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Hello** I work on create bootstrap testimonials using bootstrap carousel, so I Divided every item into 3 boxes and it's work well but the problem will be appear in responsive media screen that the section height will be not proper:

[image]

so my Idea is the JQuery code will check If the window width is less than 767px then will cut the .col-xs-12:eq(1) and append it after .item then wrap it in row Div then Wrap it in .item Div:

**Here a simple example:**

Before:

```
<div class="item active">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <!-- Text Layer -->
        <div class="text-image">
            Hello World
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <!-- Text Layer -->
        <div class="text-image">
            Hello World
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <!-- Text Layer -->
        <div class="text-image">
            Hello World
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After: the code will check if the window width is less than 767px then will do this actions:

```
<div class="item active">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <!-- Text Layer -->
            <div class="text-image">
                Hello World
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 moved">
            <!-- Text Layer -->
            <div class="text-image">
                Hello World
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 moved">
                <!-- Text Layer -->
                <div class="text-image">
                    Hello World
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Here my snippet:**

```js
; (function ($) {
    "use strict";
    var $windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if ($windowWidth < 767) {
        $('#pencil-testimonials_2 .item').each(function (index, element) {
            $(this).find(".col-xs-12:eq(1)").addClass('moved').appendTo($(this)).wrap('<div class = "row"> </div>').wrap('<div class = "item" > </div>');
            $(this).find(".col-xs-12:eq(2)").addClass('moved').appendTo($(this)).wrap('<div class = "row"> </div>').wrap('<div class = "item" > </div>');
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#pencil-testimonials_2 {
  min-height: 375px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color:aquamarine;
}
#pencil-testimonials_2 .carousel-indicators {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#pencil-testimonials_2 .carousel-indicators > li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 3px;
  border:1px solid #838383;
  background-color:transparent;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
#pencil-testimonials_2 .carousel-indicators > li.active {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: #838383;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
#pencil-testimonials_2 .text-image{
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="pencil-testimonials_2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover" data-interval="100000" data-duration="1000">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#pencil-testimonials_2" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
            </li>
            <li data-target="#pencil-testimonials_2" data-slide-to="1">
            </li>
            <li data-target="#pencil-testimonials_2" data-slide-to="2">

            </li>
            <li data-target="#pencil-testimonials_2" data-slide-to="3">

            </li>
            <li data-target="#pencil-testimonials_2" data-slide-to="4">

            </li>
            <li data-target="#pencil-testimonials_2" data-slide-to="5">

            </li>
        </ol>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            <div class="text-image">
                                Hello World
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            <div class="text-image">
                                Hello World
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            <div class="text-image">
                                Hello World
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End of First Slide -->
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            <div class="text-image">
                                Hello World
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            <div class="text-image">
                                Hello World
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            <div class="text-image">
                                Hello World
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End of Second Slide -->
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            <div class="text-image">
                                Hello World
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            <div class="text-image">
                                Hello World
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            <div class="text-image">
                                Hello World
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End of Third Slide -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In my projects I depend on bootstrap Grid and carousel.js only

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do:

```css
.carousel.slide {
  min-height: 375px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color:aquamarine;
}
.carousel.slide .carousel-indicators {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.carousel.slide .carousel-indicators > li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 3px;
  border:1px solid #838383;
  background-color:transparent;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.carousel.slide .carousel-indicators > li.active {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: #838383;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
.carousel.slide .text-image{
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="pencil-testimonials_1" class="carousel slide hidden-xs hidden-sm" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover" data-interval="100000" data-duration="1000">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#pencil-testimonials_1" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
  </li>
  <li data-target="#pencil-testimonials_1" data-slide-to="1">
  </li>
  <li data-target="#pencil-testimonials_1" data-slide-to="2">
  </li>
 </ol>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
   <div class="item active">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="text-image">
       Hello World 1
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="text-image">
       Hello World 2
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="text-image">
       Hello World 3
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="text-image">
       Hello World 4
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="text-image">
       Hello World 5
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="text-image">
       Hello World 6
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="text-image">
       Hello World 7
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="text-image">
       Hello World 8
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="text-image">
       Hello World 9
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="pencil-testimonials_2" class="carousel slide hidden-md hidden-lg" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover" data-interval="100000" data-duration="1000">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#pencil-testimonials_2" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
  </li>
  <li data-target="#pencil-testimonials_2" data-slide-to="1">
  </li>
  <li data-target="#pencil-testimonials_2" data-slide-to="2">
  </li>
    <li data-target="#pencil-testimonials_2" data-slide-to="3">
  </li>
  <li data-target="#pencil-testimonials_2" data-slide-to="4">
  </li>
  <li data-target="#pencil-testimonials_2" data-slide-to="5">
  </li>
    <li data-target="#pencil-testimonials_2" data-slide-to="6">
  </li>
  <li data-target="#pencil-testimonials_2" data-slide-to="7">
  </li>
  <li data-target="#pencil-testimonials_2" data-slide-to="8">
  </li>
 </ol>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
   <div class="item active">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="text-image">
       Hello World 1
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="text-image">
       Hello World 2
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="text-image">
       Hello World 3
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="text-image">
       Hello World 4
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="text-image">
       Hello World 5
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="text-image">
       Hello World 6
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="text-image">
       Hello World 7
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="text-image">
       Hello World 8
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="text-image">
       Hello World 9
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Basically, you just create two carousels and hide the one you don't want using Bootstrap's utility classes: `hidden-xs`, `hidden-sm`, `hidden-md` and `hidden-lg`. If you need more control, you can always create a third one for tablets.

Comment: No it's what I need, What I need is avoid the big height in mobile responsive thank you

Comment: Thank very much Andrei for trying help me, see the testimonials section in this website [link](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/seo-boost-seodigital-company-html-template-with-visual-builder-and-dashboard-pages/full_screen_preview/19649612) see it in desktop version then resize the browser

Comment: I tried and I've reached to this solution:
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpxvLhn5/5/)

Comment: Your javascript doesn't seem to work. When I make it large, they are still only 1/slide. I believe you should use [slick](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/). It has a very handy [.responsive](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/#responsive-option-example) config property.

Comment: Thank you, But I don't prefer depend on any plugin, bootstrap carousel is rich and It can be used to do anything so could you please help me in this issue

Comment: @MichaelNeas I've come up with a working solution and updated the answer. Note I also deleted my previous comments as they were referring to the old solution.